# Alamofire post request with [UInt8]

Tags: swift, alamofire

I need to send a UInt8 array to the server and get another UInt8 array in response, how can I do this using Alamofire?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, then use [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper) and Alamofire together:

this sample class model for create post body from Mappbable (Read ObjectMapper the user guide):

```
import ObjectMapper
public class MyClassName: NSObject, Mappable {
    
    // MARK: - variable
    public var offset: UInt?
    public var data: [UInt8]?
    
    // MARK: - lifecycle
    required public override init() {}
    
    public required init?(map: Map) {}
    
    // MARK: - helper function
    public func mapping(map: Map) {
        
        self.offset <- map["offset"] // set offset
        self.data <- map["data"] // set UInt8 with key data in json, you can set any key here
    }
}
```

and use Router (create Router with Alamofire) for readable and easy use for network layer like below code:

```
import Alamofire
enum NetworkRouter: URLRequestConvertible {

// case
case postData(UserLoginModel)
    
    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
            
            // http method
            var method: HTTPMethod {
                switch self {
                    
                case .postData:
                    return .post
                }
            }
            
            // params
            let params: [String: Any]? = {
                switch self {
                case .postData(let myObject):
                    return myObject.toJSON() // toJSON method on ObjectMapper library, and here set post body
                }
            }()
            
            // url
            let url: URL = {
                var relativePath: String?
                var baseUrl: String? = ""
                
                switch self {
                case .postData:
                    relativePath = "endpoint"
                    baseUrl = "https://baseURL/"
                    break
                }
                
                var url = URL.init(string: baseUrl!)!
                var urlString =  ""
                if let relativePath = relativePath {
                    switch self {
                    default:
                        url = url.appendingPathComponent(relativePath)
                        return url
                    }
                }
                
                return url
            }()
            
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue
            urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 60.0
            }
            
            let encoding: ParameterEncoding = {
                switch method {
                case .get:
                    return URLEncoding.queryString
                    
                default:
                    return JSONEncoding.default
                }
            }()
            
            return try encoding.encode(urlRequest, with: params)
        }
}
```

now just call apiCall with Alamofire:

```
let r = NetworkRouter.postData(putCreateObjectHere) // create instance from MyClassName
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.sample.api", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent)
    let request = AF.request(r)
        .validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 300)
        .responseJSON(queue: queue) { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                 // handler success
                break
                
            case .failure(let error):
                // handler error
                break
            }
    }
```

Comment: if I understood correctly this code converts UInt8 array to json, and I need to transfer UInt8 array to the server (iot device)

Comment: hi, you can set end point address (server) inside NetworkRouter enum and call api with last code snippet.